# How to disable and enable datetimepicker jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement like enabling and disabling [datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) plugin from input box.

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="opt1" data-type="date">opt1</option>
<option value="opt2" data-type="string">opt2</option>
</input><input id="inp">

<script>
$('#sel').on('change', function(){
   var type = $('this').find('option:selected').data(type);
   if(type == 'date'){
      //enable calendar
      $('#inp').datetimepicker();
   } else {
      //need to disable
   }
});
</script>
```

Want to enable if type is date if not need to disable calendar. Any help appreciable.

Comment: And what is not working here?

Comment: See else block , if 'type' is other than date i want to remove calendar from input box and work like normal input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll find time and read `datetimepicker` [manual](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) you will see a couple of methods **even** with examples:

`hide` - Hide Datetimepicker

`toggle` - Show/Hide Datetimepicker

`destroy` - Destroy datetimepicker

Now, choose which one you want.

Comment: Yes, destroy is working fine for me.
Thank you, i didn't seen the manual just taken some example and worked on it.